# find_all() returns only first item of the list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some trouble with BeautifulSoup, with find_all() method. I am trying get text between all `p` tags, but it returns me only first element of the list. Actually list has only one item. Why find_all() method return only one item?

It's part of code I want to extract:

```
<div class="post-content">
 <p>If you’re not familiar with Deep Image, it’s an amazing tool which allows you to increase the size of an image and upgrade its quality at the same time.</p>

 <p>You can find it, and use for free <a href="https://deep-image.ai/">HERE</a></p>

 <p><em>The goal of this blog post is to focus on the main changes and showcase the results of DI 2.0 algorithms.</em></p>

 <p>As we all know a picture is worth a thousand words. So we will let the enhanced pictures speak for themselves. All pictures you can see below were processed using Deep Image algorithms.</p>

 <h2 id="what-has-changed">What has changed</h2>

 <p>Here are all the main improvements added to Deep Image 2.0:</p>
</div>
```

And it's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://teonite.com/blog/deep-image-2-showcasing-results/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

for article in soup.find_all(class_='post-content'):
    print(article.p.text)
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: The sample input only has one item with the requested class.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for all tags with the class `post-content`. While there is only one such element, `find_all` returns a list with a single entry. So you only have one iteration in your `for` loop and you print only the text of the first `p` tag within this iteration.

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = '''
<div class="post-content">
 <p>If you’re not familiar with Deep Image, it’s an amazing tool which allows you to increase the size of an image and upgrade its quality at the same time.</p>

 <p>You can find it, and use for free <a href="https://deep-image.ai/">HERE</a></p>

 <p><em>The goal of this blog post is to focus on the main changes and showcase the results of DI 2.0 algorithms.</em></p>

 <p>As we all know a picture is worth a thousand words. So we will let the enhanced pictures speak for themselves. All pictures you can see below were processed using Deep Image algorithms.</p>

 <h2 id="what-has-changed">What has changed</h2>

 <p>Here are all the main improvements added to Deep Image 2.0:</p>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find(class_='post-content')
for p in div.find_all('p'):
    print(p.text)
```

And you will get your desired output of all text within `p` tags since we now search for the element with the class `post-content` and subsequently search for all `p` tags within this element.

Answer (score 1):

The command `print(article.p.text)` will find and print only first `<p>` tag. To get text of whole article, you can use for example `get_text()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://teonite.com/blog/deep-image-2-showcasing-results/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')

for article in soup.find_all(class_='post-content'):
    print(article.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Prints:

```
If you’re not familiar with Deep Image, it’s an amazing tool which allows you to increase the size of an image and upgrade its quality at the same time.
You can find it, and use for free
HERE
The goal of this blog post is to focus on the main changes and showcase the results of DI 2.0 algorithms.
As we all know a picture is worth a thousand words. So we will let the enhanced pictures speak for themselves. All pictures you can see below were processed using Deep Image algorithms.
What has changed
Here are all the main improvements added to Deep Image 2.0:
You are now able to use a new algorithm to magnify the image two-fold and four-fold. It is based on Generative Adversarial Networks.
The quality of the algorithm has been improved - there are less artefacts and even smoother edges in the enhanced images.
We have delivered a new, more reliable asynchronous queue architecture and task processing, based on microservices.
You can now enjoy a fully redesigned web application
A few examples
Please keep in mind that Deep Image was trained to do a very particular job - it will increase the size of the picture as well as improve its quality once it’s enlarged. It will not improve the quality of the image you have resized before.
Check out those awesome results!
The improvements are clearly visible.
Think about all those old photos you will be able to enhance!
You are the main reason we’re working on those cool projects, so we’d love to get your feedback.
Contact us
and let us know what you think!
```

NOTE:

To get string decoding right, use `result.content` instead of `result.text`.